# Draw a d3 trend line with different color and width for different segments

Tags: d3.js, trendline

I am trying to draw a trend line using d3.js v3 , but the stroke color and stroke-width
need to be different for 4 segments in the trend line according to some conditions.

From what I found online, I was told, I need to draw 4 different paths.
The problem with this is I want the trendline as a whole to be interpolated with "basis" .With drawing 4 separate paths , each with their interpolation set to "basis" , I get a trendline which doesn't look smooth.[image]

Is there a way to draw a smooth trendline with the different colors and widths?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar at the moment and was wondering if you found a good solution? investigating using D3 and a line chart where it is realtime chart but there is a horizontal line such as this to represent *now* - left of now midpoint is historical data and right of the now midpoint is future prediction data. very similar visualization to this - do you remember where you netted out? lmk please!

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/applying-colour-gradient-to-graph-line.html) article online. It could solve your smooth application of different colors in a graph line. As for the thickness of the line graph, you could tweak the given code to get the desired results.

Hope this helps.